# Access create table vba

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

The idea is to type in the name of a new table into a form field and click a button to make a table on a remote database with the name the user enters into the field. However, the new table is created with the name “NewTableName” and not the value in the NewTableName field. Does anyone know of a different syntax or a better function? Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub MakeTable_Click()
  Dim dbConnectStr As String
  Dim Catalog As Object
  Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
  Dim dbPath As String

    dbPath = "\\JAMWHITL-WS01\AccessBackEnds\Assessments\AssessmentsBackEnd.accdb"
    dbConnectStr = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=" & dbPath & ";"

      Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
      With cnt
        .Open dbConnectStr
        .Execute "CREATE TABLE [NewTableName] (Question Text, ID COUNTER)"

      End With
      Set cnt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable equal to the text property of the textbox they enter the table name in.  Then say something like the following:

```
"CREATE TABLE [" + variable + "] (Question Text, ID COUNTER)"
```

Comment: Don't forget to add in the square brackets if the user might type a name with spaces...